# How to capture change along an axis?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Assume we have a moving object. I want to capture its change, however I'm only interested in a vertical movement. I tried to modify this code:

```
# movement frames
frame1 = cv2.imread('frame1.jpg')
frame2 = cv2.imread('frame2.jpg')

prev = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # to gray scale
hsv1 = np.zeros_like(frame1)  # `hsv` into full green image
hsv1[..., 1] = 255

nxt = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev=prev, next=nxt, flow=None, pyr_scale=0.5, levels=3, winsize=15,
                                    iterations=3, poly_n=5, poly_sigma=1.1, flags=0)

mag1, ang1 = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
hsv1[..., 0] = ang1 * 180 / np.pi / 2
hsv1[..., 2] = cv2.normalize(src=mag1, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
rgb1 = cv2.cvtColor(hsv1, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

However, I didn't manage to achieve what I wanted. My question is: what's the easiest way of capuring the change along Y axis only?

EDIT: Two of the example images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you please share your images?

Comment: Added. Those two are quite far apart. If required, it might be possible for me to use more FPS in the project, however the less I need the better.